# WPF DataGrid SelectAll Button appearing once DataGrid is Loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

I am new to WPF and am working on a project where I am using WPF and DataGrid to show a DataTable.

I have both Column and Row Headers visible and the issue I have is that the SelectAll button at the top left of the DataGrid does not appear until the method calling the WPF window has completed. This results in the Column Headers being misaligned until the SelectAll button appears.

I have recreated the issue in a very simple project.

I can see the SelectAll button in Design Mode and the result is still the same. Can anyone help please? Pictures below show what I am talking about.

[image: Image001]

[image: Image002]

my XAML is below followed by the C# behind it that creates the DataTable

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450px" Width="800px">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
           x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="Border"
                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                                                  Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}"
                                                  Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Stroke>
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                                                  Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}"
                                                  Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>

                        <Polygon x:Name="Arrow"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                 Margin="8,8,3,3"
                                 Opacity="0.55"
                                 Points="0,10 10,10 10,0"
                                 Stretch="Uniform"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                            <Polygon.Fill>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" />
                            </Polygon.Fill>
                        </Polygon>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="73*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="502*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="BtnImport" Content="Import"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Height="20" Width="100">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="BOLD"><Run Text="Import to AutoCAD"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock><Run Text="Click or press ALT+ENTER"/></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="BtnCancel" Content="Cancel"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Height="20" Width="100">

        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="BOLD"><Run Text="Cancel"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock><Run Text="Click or press ESCAPE"/></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0">
        <StatusBarItem >
            <TextBlock x:Name="AppsVer"><Run Text="AppsVer"/></TextBlock>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>

    <DataGrid x:Name="ExportGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ColumnHeaderHeight="50" HeadersVisibility="All" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="True" RowHeaderWidth="40"/>
</Grid>
```

```
using System.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ExportGrid.ItemsSource = MakeTable().DefaultView;
    }

    public static DataTable MakeTable()
    {
        var tbl = new DataTable();

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            tbl.Columns.Add("Column" + i, typeof(int));
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= 30; j++)
        {
            var nuRow = tbl.NewRow();
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
            {

                nuRow[k] = j;
            }
            tbl.Rows.Add(nuRow);
        }
        return tbl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem with your implementation? The grid is rendered correctly as soon as the window shows up. Can you provide further explanation or a code where the problem is visible?

Comment: Hi Eike B thanks for your comment. Did you compile this and run from the .exe? Because I agree from the .exe it renders fine. If you run it from inside Visual Studio is when you see the symptom I describe.

Comment: The project I am working on is a plugin for AutoCAD and even if i build a release version and run inside AutoCAD instead of debug from Visual Studio I still get the shift in column headers.

Comment: I ran it from vs with debugger. Still Same result

Comment: Same result as in It render correctly or same as I am reporting?

Comment: Same result as it was working correctly

Comment: If you run a screen capture while running the .exe and play it back frame by frame it still exhibits the feature. but just much quicker. In my project it is quite obvious. This is obviously a feature of the DataGrid in WPF. It just looks a bit pants

Comment: I am still having this problem. The SelectAll button does not appear runtime until the method calling it completes. Is this a feature of WPF DataGrid. Is anyone able to tell me what I am doing wrong please???

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your issue in the way you describe.

But according to your description, it could be a solution to fill the grid with an asynchronous method. In this case, the view will not block until the method finishes and the grid should be drawn correctly.

I added a code snippet which will fill the grid asynchronous:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MakeTable();
        }

        public async void MakeTable()
        {
            var task = await Task<DataTable>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var tbl = new DataTable();
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    tbl.Columns.Add("Coloumn" + i, typeof(int));
                }

                for (int j = 0; j <= 30; j++)
                {
                    var nuRow = tbl.NewRow();
                    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                    {

                        nuRow[k] = j;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                    tbl.Rows.Add(nuRow);
                }

                return tbl;
            });

            ExportGrid.ItemsSource = task.DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Eike B. Thank you for your comment and suggestion. I have tried your code snippet above and the issue still remains. Is there any way I could create a DataGrid as an object and then pass that to the window? Would that even help?? I have tried and can successfully create the Grid but then I can't get it to show on the window.

Comment: Hey K.Scott, I am not sure what you are trying to do? You want to create the complete Grid in code behind and then add it to your View? Well, you could do that, but its a nasty workaround. How to do this, you should search something like creating Usercontrols in CodeBehind. Is it possible, that the issue is based in some datatemplate which is inherited to your current control? That could be the reason why I am not able to reproduce this issue. How are you navigating to the view? Are you using any libraries like Prism?